# get the console output and print sametime in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file

i want to print console output and get at the sametime.
i tried to this with below code to get and printing the result but it's not work.
how can i do this?

code:

```
  set myvar="C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" asd.iss /SSign_PATH="%cd%\DigitalSign\signtool.exe sign $p"
  for /f "delims=" %%i in ('%myvar%') DO (
  echo %%i
  set OUTPATH=%%i )
```

result:

```
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error message is arising from the FOR /F command.

**Solution:** A small change to the FOR /F statement

```
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^"%myvar%^"') DO (
```

**Explanation:**

When executing a command via something like `FOR /F .... IN ('command') DO ...`, the command is executed in a new cmd.exe process via a command that looks like the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c command
```

Your command requires quotes around the executable path because of the spaces. So your command, as currently written, becomes:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c "C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" asd.iss /SSign_PATH="%cd%\DigitalSign\signtool.exe sign $p"
```

But CMD.EXE has an unfortunate design that if the first character of the command is a quote, then it normally strips the outer most quotes from the command string before it is executed. So the command becomes

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" asd.iss /SSign_PATH="%cd%\DigitalSign\signtool.exe sign $p
```

Looking at the above, you should be able to see why you are getting the error message.

The solution is to add an extra set of quotes around the entire command that will get stripped. You want the command to look like:

```
C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" asd.iss /SSign_PATH="%cd%\DigitalSign\signtool.exe sign $p""
```

But you don't want the extra set of quotes to throw off the batch parser, so they should be escaped within the `IN()` clause.

Comment: thank you for answer. now i know why it's not work. thanks. but something has going to wrong. it's successfully to run program with the fixed code `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('^"%myvar%^"') DO (` but unfortunately  the program(iscc.exe) seems cant get a argument perfectly. iscc.exe are just showing default print message. running `cmd /c  "%myvar%"` are successful but `for .. in('^"%myvar%^"')` arent.